# Mongo db upgrade Java driver and morphia version Compatibility

Tags: mongodb, github, mongodb-java, morphia

I am trying to upgrade mongodb from **3.0.x to 3.4.x.**

Currently I am using morphia 1.2.2 (Driver version 3.2.2) and 1.1.1(Driver version is 3.0.2) in two different project which using same database.

I saw the Mongodb JAVA driver compatibility :http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/upgrading/ 
said I need java driver version 3.4 for mongodb 3.4.

Is that mean I have to upgrade my morphia also in order to match the mongodb Java driver compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

Morphia 1.2.2 should continue to work just fine with the 3.4 driver.  I can't vouch for the absolute latest drivers but I would expect that they probably also work with that version of Morphia.

Still, though, you should consider updating to the latest Morphia, too.